Modal de bootstrap se abre solo: no espera al evento click
Estoy creando un plugin y necesito crear un formulario que me permita ingresar datos a la BD. Opté por bootstrap para que muestre una ventana modal. Al momento de implementarla, cuando entro a la sección de mi plugin, la ventana se abre sola (no espera el evento click).

y cuando la cierro, y doy clic en el botón Nuevo Registro me sale el siguiente error en consola:

Reviso mi archivo de código de llamado al modal

y pues nada, estoy revisando qué podría ser lo malo.

El código y los mensajes de error siempre como texto, con formato. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Lo que sucede es que a tu función le falta un callback, como no tiene asume que estas intentando ejecutar el código al terminar la recarga, ya que no le estas asignado una función, prueba con esto.
$('#btnNuevo').click(function() {
   $('#nuevoRegistro').modal('show');
});

Aquí usamos function() {} como callback, es decir, la función a ejecutar.

Me encantaría saber el porque del voto negativo cuando la respuesta es correcta, estoy abierto a cualquier tipo de retroalimentación ya que he recibido votos negativos en muchas respuestas que a mi consideración son correctas.

Hola! gracias por comentar. lo hice pero no funcionó... cuando entro al sector me sale la ventana modal... salgo de ahí y cuando doy click me bota error en la consola. Uso el bootstrap actual 5.3

Y funcionó! le tuve que cambiar el nombre de id="btnNuevo" por id="btnNuevoTC" y apliqué el código indicado. Demasiado raro, pero quizá el nombre btnNuevo ya es muy usado... quizá. Muchas gracias, ahora sí funciona. Seguiré programando.!

@JefferzonBol Seguramente, porque respondiste una pregunta sin código y con imágenes, te doy el +1 para reponer el balance en el universo

Es raro, tengo votos negativos en otras respuestas cuyas preguntas si estaban trabajadas, pero bueno, siempre agradezco la retroalimentación @Yussef de hecho, justo después de escribir mi primer comentario recibi 3 votos negativos consecutivos en otras 3 respuestas.

@Jefferzon, paisano, yo generalmente no le pongo mucho coco a los votos negativos y te sugiero hacer lo mismo, pero tienes la opción de llamar la atención de algún moderador para revisar si hay alguién que está votando serialmente tus respuestas. No sé si 3 o 4 votos sean suficientes para levantar las alarmas. Por otro lado, es una buena idea responder a preguntas bien formuladas y que siguen las reglas, como se sugiere en [answer].  Un saludo y una invitación a seguir aportando desde la tierra de la eterna primavera! :)
